# How do I set a custom screen resolution as permanent?

Tags: display, resolution

I am using the latest elementary OS build 0.3.2. 
I need a screen resolution of 1280x800_60.00. 
I can set the desired screen resolution using xrandr.
This change is only temporary and disappears upon reboot.
How do I set the 1280x800_60.00 screen resolution as permanent?
I have searched the web and tried various suggestions for this with no success.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command each time you log in by adding it to `~/.profile`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/270050) for more info.

I'm assuming here that this resolution doesn't appear in Display settings because it isn't a native resolution of your monitor. (If it *does* appear in display settings, using that would be the easiest way to make the change.)